# string_agg: more than two attributes concatenation

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

I am using `postgresql 9.0` 
I am wonder if its possible to concatenate three attributes together.

this is how I concatenate two attributes (book & the comma):

```
SELECT string_agg(book, ',') FROM authors where id = 1;


| book1,book2,book3|
--------------------
```

how can I do something like below:

```
SELECT string_agg(name, ':', book, ',') FROM authors where id = 1;

| Ahmad: book1,book2,book3|
  ----------------
```

can some one help? thanks.

Comment: "this is how I concatenate two attributes" - that looks to me like concatenating all the values of one field, not two fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just concatenate the fields like this:

```
SELECT name || ':' || string_agg(book, ',') FROM authors where id = 1;
```

**Edit:**

If your SQL returns multiple names you need to group by name (if you have multiple authors with the same name it gets a bit more complicated. I won't cover that case in this answer):

```
SELECT name || ':' || string_agg(book, ',') 
  FROM authors where id = 1 
 GROUP BY name;
```

If you want the books in alphabetical order you can add an `ORDER BY` for the books:

```
SELECT name || ':' || string_agg(book, ',') WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY book 
  FROM authors where id = 1 
 GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name || ': ' || string_agg(book, ',') FROM authors where id = 1 group by name ;
```